# How do I get one of my words to print vertically?

Tags: java, for-loop, printing, crossword

The words in this code are supposed to intersect at a common letter and print off as many times as the words can intersect each other.

I have the correct amount of times but the words are not formatting the correct way.

It is supposed to look like this:

```
 b
lottery
 a
 t

  b
  o
  a
lottery

   b
   o
   a
lottery
```

But mine are printing out like this:

```
b
lotto
    a
    t
                b
lotto
    a
    t
                b
lotto
    a
    t
```

My code is displayed below, what is wrong with my printing method that is causing this?

```
 public class Assg23
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            String w1 = args[0];
            String w2 = args[1];

            int numberOfCrosses = 0;

            int pos1=0;
            int pos2=0;


            for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j < w2.length(); j++)
                {   
                    if(w1.charAt(i) == w2.charAt(j))
                    {
                        numberOfCrosses++;
                        crossesAt(w1, pos1, w2, pos2);
                        printCross(w1, pos1, w2, pos2);
                    }
                }
            }

        if(numberOfCrosses == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Words do not cross");
        }
    }

    private static boolean crossesAt(String w1, int pos1, String w2, int pos2)
    {
        if(w1.charAt(pos1) == w2.charAt(pos2))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private static void printCross(String w1, int pos1, String w2, int pos2)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < w2.length(); j++)
            {
                if((j== pos1) && i<w2.length())
                {
                    System.out.println(w2.charAt(i));
                }
                if((i == pos2) && j<w1.length())
                {   
                    System.out.print(w1.charAt(j));
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }   

            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: You are already comparing for equality and hence do not need `crossesAt` method invocation.

Comment: when I take out crossesAt it still prints the same way @akhil_mittal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a correct version of your `main()` method.  You'll notice that I removed the `crossesAt()` method because all it does is to compare two characters which can be done in less than one line of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String w1 = args[0];
    String w2 = args[1];

    int numberOfCrosses = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < w2.length(); j++) {
            if (w1.charAt(i) == w2.charAt(j)) {
                numberOfCrosses++;
                printCross(w1, i, w2, j);
            }
        }
    }

    if (numberOfCrosses == 0) {
        System.out.println("Words do not cross");
    }
}
```

And here is a correctly working implementation of your `printCross()` method:

```
private static void printCross(String w1, int pos1, String w2, int pos2) {
    // you can replace this for-loop with the line that follows it
    // if you don't get compiler errors
    String spaces = "";
    for (int i=0; i < pos1; ++i) spaces += " ";
    //String spaces = String.format(String.format("%%0%dd", pos1), 0).replace("0", " ");

    for (int i=0; i < w2.length(); ++i) {
        if (i == pos2) {
            System.out.println(w1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(spaces + w2.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of `printCross()` being used:

```
printCross("boat", 1, "lottery", 1);
printCross("coffee", 4, "beverage", 3);
```

**Output:**

```
 l
boat
 t
 t
 e
 r
 y
    b
    e
    v
coffee
    r
    a
    g
    e
```

Comment: I put that in and get this error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.DuplicateFormatFlagsException: Flags = '0'
 at java.util.Formatter$Flags.parse(Formatter.java:4443)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.flags(Formatter.java:2640)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2709)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
 at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
 at Assg23.printCross(Assg23.java:53)
 at Assg23.main(Assg23.java:27)`

Comment: The code runs fine in my local IntelliJ. My guess is your configuration has some sort of problem.

Comment: Is there something I am supposed to download? What do you mean my configuration?

Comment: line 53 is: String spaces = String.format(String.format("%%0%dd", pos2), 0).replace("0", " ");

Comment: the words lottery and boat are just examples, the user is allowed to put any two words in

Comment: Try my code again, I removed the formatting line which should not have been causing problems but for some reason was in your case.

Comment: DuplicateFormatFlagsException is a pretty self-explanatory exception name, try removing the duplicate "%" in "%%0%dd" and see if that helps.

Comment: @JamesS The strange this is that my IntelliJ whistled along as if nothing were wrong.  Don't know why his IDE is choking.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hmm, that's bizarre. Maybe he should try surrounding the format in a try/catch, call getFlags() on the exception and output the result.

Comment: I'm thinking it's a Java version setting issue, or his IDE has some strict mode in place.  Anyway, I just copied that format expression from another SO post, and it also ran fine in IntelliJ with no problems.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the code still isn't working it is not printing out right. `boat
o
t
t
e
r
y
boat
o
t
t
e
r
y
boat
o
t
t
e
r
y`

Comment: boat is supposed to be vertical, while instead lottery is. And it is still not formatting right

Comment: Everything is good except I need the w1 and w2 to switch positions. Boat is supposed to be vertical and lottery is supposed to horizontal

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Did you change it?

Comment: Just updated it.  It should work as you wanted now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [solution proposed by Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33207312) (credit goes to him) here is the complete code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String w1 = "boat";
        String w2 = "lottery";

        int numberOfCrosses = 0;

        int pos1=0;
        int pos2=0;
        int spaces = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < w2.length(); j++)
            {
                spaces = 0;
                if(w1.charAt(i) == w2.charAt(j))
                {
                    numberOfCrosses++;
                    printCross(w1, i, w2);
                } else spaces++;
            }
        }

        if(numberOfCrosses == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Words do not cross");
        }
    }

    private static void printCross(String w1, int pos, String w2) {
        String spaces = String.format(String.format("%%0%dd", pos1), 0).replace("0", " ");
        int lengthToTraverse = (w1.length() > w2.length()) ? (w1.length()) : (w2.length());
        for (int i=0; i < lengthToTraverse; ++i) {
            if (i == pos) {
                System.out.println(w2);
            }
            else {
                if(i<w1.length()) {
                    System.out.println(spaces + w1.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have added check for `i` and have removed one extra parameter in method. The output it:

`b
lottery
 a
 t
   b
   o
   a
lottery
   b
   o
   a
lottery`

Comment: lottery and boat are just examples the user can input any words

Comment: I don't see anything different about it you are still using lottery and boat for the strings

Comment: @anderkat97 His code should run for _any_ two strings which you define to overlap (assuming he took my method verbatim).

Comment: will give error as functional parameter variable name given as pos where as using with pos1